# hide list bullets react CSS

Tags: reactjs, styles

i am trying to hide the bullets sign of list
i have tried this

```
  <ul sytle={ styles.ulclass }>
  <li>.
      .
      .
        </li>
```

and

```
   ulclass:{
   display:'flex',
   flexDirection: 'row',
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   listStyleType:'none',
   margin:'0px',
   padding:'0px',
   overflow:'hidden',
   textDecoration:'none',

  },
```

but

```
  listStyleType:'none'
```

not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this how you can apply `listStyleType:'none'`

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <ul style={mystyle}>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  );


const mystyle={
  listStyleType:'none'
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-grothendieck-esdwt)

Answer (score 1):

Just write this

```
<ul style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>
.. </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo in the prop:

```
<ul sytle={ styles.ulclass }>
```

It should be:

```
<ul style={ styles.ulclass }>
//--^^^^^-----
```